# Is there an "OS Login" equivalent in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In Google Cloud Compute Engine, [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/) is really useful for having multiple users share the same instances on one file server. In a nutshell, it automatically adds the user to the instance. In AWS, I see similar [resources](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/), but it looks like you have to do it manually for each instance, and for each user. Is there a way to have this done automatically in AWS EC2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Automatic Linux account lifecycle management and Fine grained
>   authorization using Google Cloud IAM

I did not use os login but the link you provided and their main feature is most similar to OpsWork of AWS like allow the user to ssh and restrict the access of each user and provide ssh access to IAM user.

**To authorize SSH for an IAM user similar to OS feature (Fine grained authorization using Google Cloud IAM )**

> In the AWS OpsWorks Stacks navigation pane, click Permissions.
>
> Select SSH/RDP for the desired AWS Identity and Access Management
>   (IAM) user to grant the necessary permissions. If you want to allow
>   the user to use sudo to elevate privileges—for example, to run agent
>   CLI commands—select `sudo/admin` also.

[image]

**Importing Users into AWS OpsWorks Stacks is similar to OS login feature (Automatic Linux account lifecycle management)**

> Administrative users can import IAM users into AWS OpsWorks Stacks;
>   they can also import AWS OpsWorks Stacks users from one regional
>   endpoint to another. When you import IAM users to AWS OpsWorks Stacks,
>   you import them to one of the AWS OpsWorks Stacks regional endpoints.
>   If you want an IAM user to be available in more than one region, you
>   must import the user to that region.
>   [image]

**Unix IDs and Users Created Outside AWS OpsWorks Stacks is similar to Ability to import existing Linux accounts**

> AWS OpsWorks assigns users on AWS OpsWorks Stacks instances Unix ID
>   (UID) values between 2000 and 4000. Because AWS OpsWorks reserves the
>   2000-4000 range of UIDs, users that you create outside of AWS OpsWorks
>   (by using cookbook recipes, or by importing users into AWS OpsWorks
>   from IAM, for example) can have UIDs that are overwritten by AWS
>   OpsWorks Stacks for another user. This can result in users that you
>   have created outside of AWS OpsWorks Stacks not showing up in data bag
>   search results, or being excluded from the AWS OpsWorks Stacks
>   built-in sync_remote_users operation.
>   [image]

So  I think OpsWork is the best choice for you if we compare this with Os login of Google cloud.

There are lot of more feature of OpsWork but in context of Oslogin that seems similar to me. you can further explore [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_classic.html).

[opsworks-security-users-manage-import.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/opsworks-security-users-manage-import.html)

[workinginstances-ssh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-ssh.html)

[configuration-management-with-aws-opsworks](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/configuration-management-with-aws-opsworks-november-2016-webinar-series)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EC2 Instance Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/introducing-amazon-ec2-instance-connect/).

> you can control SSH access to your instances using AWS Identity and
>   Access Management (IAM) policies as well as audit connection requests
>   with AWS CloudTrail events. In addition, you can leverage your
>   existing SSH keys or further enhance your security posture by
>   generating one-time use SSH keys each time an authorized user connects.

Comment: EC2 Instance Connect looks like it's in the right direction, but I think the key feature that it's missing is the ability to transfer the user settings to the VMs; in other words, these two features in OS Login:


- Configures NSS (Name Service Switch) functionality to provide the OS Login user information to the operating system.


- Adds a set of PAM configurations to authorize the user login. PAM configurations perform IAM permission checks for login and administrative access. These PAM configurations also perform other tasks such as setting up the Linux user account's home directory.